# XHR request hangs in safari on el capitan

Tags: angularjs, safari, xmlhttprequest

I have a wierd situation that we cannot figure out or make sense of.

We have a web application.  If i use chrome on osx it works.  If i use safari and hit our QA environment it works.  If i run safari on Mavericks against my local dev machine it works.  If i run safari on el capitan against my local dev machine to does NOT work.

What we see is that the browser is able to directly download assets but xhr requests sit there and spin indefinitely.  One of the examples is were using angular with routing and when angular makes the xhr for the html page it sits there and hangs.  However if i just put the same url into the browser itself it pulls down the html just fine.

This has stumped us.  It worked fine in Mavericks, it works fine in our QA environment.  We have turned off all firewalls on the local dev machines.  The iis logs on the local dev never see the request for the html file.  Chrome on el capitan works just fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd start with the usual suspects: debug to observe what XHR requests are actually being sent and what is being received. Look for JavaScript errors in its console. El Cap did introduce some "breaking changes" to Safari.

Comment: As far as i can tell the browser is blocking the request.  The IIS server doesnt seem to see the request at all.  But it doesnt return any errors or anything, eventually it just times out as red in web inspector with no response code or anything

Comment: Are you saying that you can see, from local logs, that the request is being *sent* (**and**: "apparently successfully"), but that IIS has no record of having received it?  (That would be *most* unusual ...) Check very, very carefully. Your symptoms imply that someone out there is literally **dropping** the packet, as e.g. a firewall might do.  But, I would suggest "very patiently poring over the information, being very sure," before arriving at that conclusion.