# CORS OPTIONS Request Successful, but Hangs in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, angular, cors, laravel-5.3

## Safari (10 - OSX El Capitan) Issue with CORS

I'm doing a CORS POST request from AngularJS front-end to Laravel Back-end.

- In Chrome and Firefox, both OPTIONS and POST request return http status 200 OK
- In Safari 10 (OSX), both OPTIONS and POST request return http status 200 OK, **but the OPTIONS request keeps loading (http status 200 OK!)**

## Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:x.local
Origin:http://y.local
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://y.local/
```

## Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:16
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 31 Oct 2016 09:22:51 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.1
```

Safari hangs, after I get the http status 200 OK (OPTIONS request). What should I do?

Comment: Sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789251/xhr-request-hangs-in-safari-on-el-capitan (no answer)

Comment: This also looks similar https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/3hP4JpTHLYY

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, but it doesn't work for me both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Didn't look like it contains a clear solution, but it looked like some things worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

Try returning 204 No Content, that worked for me.
It is found in some examples with no further explanations.

Comment: This worked in my case. I already had "Accept" being sent to the browser as mentioned in other answers on this thread. Serving 204 worked fine, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the `Accept` header added to your CORS `AllowedHeaders` options. This solved it for me.

Your request has an Accept header of `/`, but your CORS options doesn't handle that at all. Modern browsers like Chrome can work without the headers, but Safari has not stayed up to date.

Comment: I had a similar problem as OP. Your answer helped me, but I want to clear up that I had already used a `*` in my CORS `Allowed-Headers`. This didn't work. Instead, I now used `Accept, (...more headers)` and it worked.